# Redis Exchange Error :Member "EndPoints" cannot be initialized. It is not a field or property

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

We recently updated our "StackExchange.Redis" package to **version 2.6.48**.
But now we are getting error message "**Member 'EndPoints' cannot be initialized. It is not a field or property.**"
[image]

Has the key 'EndPoints' been removed from latest package? If yes, what is its replacement? Or is there any other way to connect to a redis endpoint?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue suggests a problem with the compiler version:
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/2238

Had the same issue and this was the case.

Maybe, setting the EndPoints member by using the Add method could solve the issue too I guess:
`_configurationOptions.EndPoints.Add(argStrEndPoints);`

Comment: Calling `_configurationOptions.EndPoints.Add(argStrEndPoints);`gives the same compiler error

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with ConfigurationOptions.Parse(configString);

For exampe configString = "redis0:6380,redis1:6380,allowAdmin=true,ssl=true..."